# Grouping arraylist of objects and getting max value per group in java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, grouping

I have an arraylist called ResultList. This arraylists consists of objects (Results) which in turn have a reference to a Participant object and Competition object as attributes. What I need to do is to group this arraylist (ResultList) by Participant and then put the max result (measurement) for each Participant in a new list.

Result class:

```
public class Result {

private double measurement;
private int participantID;
private Participant participant;
private Competition competition;

public Result(double measurement, int participantID, Competition competition, Participant participant) {
    this.measurement = measurement;
    this.participant = participant;
    this.competition = competition;
}
```

Participant class:

```
public class Participant {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int id;
private String gender;
private String teamName;

public Participant(String firstName, String lastName, int id, String gender, String teamName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.id = id;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.teamName = teamName;
}
```

Finally I have the ResultList class:

```
public class ResultList {

private Scanner sc;

private String listName;
private ArrayList<Result> resultList = new ArrayList<Result>();

public ResultList(Scanner sc, String name) {
    this.sc = sc;
    this.listName = name;
}
```

In the ResultList class I have a method to sort the list using a comparator, after having iterated through it to find the results for a specific competition:

```
public void listResultsForCompetition(String competitionName) {
Iterator<Result> it = resultList.iterator();
boolean nothingFound = true;
ArrayList<Result> tempResultList = new ArrayList<Result>();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Result nextItem = (Result) it.next();
    if (nextItem.getCompetitionName().equalsIgnoreCase(competitionName)) {
        nothingFound = false;
        tempResultList.add(nextItem);
    }
}
    if (nothingFound) {
        System.out.println("Error: No results found for this event. ");
    }
    Collections.sort(tempResultList, Result.ResultComparatorMeasurement);

}
```

So now I have an arraylist called tempResultList which has all the results for a specific competition ordered by the "measurement" attribute in the Result object. What I need to do now is to somehow get the top result from each participant in the tempResultList, and store this in another list, in order to produce a list of top results by participant for a specific competition.

I've googled for hours but I can't make sense of the answers I've found, as most of them only have a simple list of integers or similarly. I've seen multiple references to maps, stream and collection methods but I can't make sense of it.

EDIT: There is no fixed amount of results or participants in the arraylist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have to **sort** something, `List` is not a perfect match of the collection. Depending on results, you have to choose best collection.

In your example, I do not see how you want to use `List<Result> tempResultList`. It seems, that you use is only as temporary collection to get you main objective - get top resulst of all participant. But I can see following things:

**First:** You already have a `List<Result> tempResultList` with **sorted** results (top results at the beginning). All you need is just iterate over this list and for each participant get the first result:

```
Map<Integer, Result> topResults =  new LinkedHashMap<>();

for(Result result : tempResultList) {
    if(!topResults.containsKey(result.getParticipant().getId()))
        topResults.put(result.getParticipant().getId(), result);
}
```

*Notes:* hree I got throug your `tempResultList` and fill a map, where key is a participant's id and a value - participant's result. If paraticipant is not in a map, then add his result to it (first one in the sorted list will be the top result). You can use here `LinkedHashMap` to sort keys in map according it apperas in the `tempResultList`, or `TreeMap` - to sort it by participant's id. Or even - 'HashMap', when you do not care about an order of `topResults.values()`.

**Second:** You can build `tempResultList` and then sort the top rated results at the same time, using `Map<Integer, Set<Result>> res`. You already has a comparator you need `Result.ResultComparatorMeasurement`. Key of the map - is a participant's id, value - sorted list of participant's results, with top results first.

```
public List<Result> listResultsForCompetition(String competitionName) {
    Map<Integer, Set<Result>> participantResults = new HashMap<>();

    for (Result result : resultList) {
        int participantId = result.getParticipant().getId();

        if (!participantResults.containsKey(participantId))
```

// TreeSet will sort results according to given comparator (top results first)
                participantResults.put(participantId, new TreeSet<>(Result.ResultComparatorMeasurement));

```
        participantResults.get(participantId).add(result);
    }

    Map<Integer, Result> topParticipantResults = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Result>> entry : participantResults.entrySet())
        topParticipantResults.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().iterator().next());

    List<Result> topResults = new ArrayList<>(topParticipantResults.values());

    return topResults;
}
```

*Notes:* I do not use `stream API` here to make it maximum clear. I use `TreeSet<Result>(comparator)` to receive a sorted set of results (**ATTENTION!!!** - `Set` use comparator to fined and exclude duplication, so your comparator should not only compare results, but work correctly where two instance of `Result` have same measurement). `Map<Integer, Set<Result>> participantResults` contains all results grouped by participant's id.

There are other way to solve this task. I gave you only 2 ideas how to do it.

Comment: Thank you Oleg, your solutions worked perfectly and helped me understand how to implement maps! Much appreciated!